# Is there any way to make this adding an infinite?

Tags: c

So I tried to make this a infinite loop of input for user and adding it. But it just end at the end. Please help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int SUM(int a)
{
  int sum = 0;
  while (a > 0) 
  {
    sum = sum + (a % 10);
    a = a / 10;
  }
  return sum;
}

int main()
{
  int x;
  printf("Enter an integer = ");

  scanf("%d", &x);

  SUM(x);

  printf("Sum digit = %d", SUM(x));
}
```

Comment: Where is the infinite loop in your code? There is only one loop (the `while` loop) and that has a definite termination clause

Comment: I'm posting this question because I don't know where to put them in

Comment: what are you trying to do? it'll be better if you add additional information about what you want to get and what you actually get

Comment: Do you mean you want an infinite loop which asks the user for another number?

Comment: Yes. So what I was trying is that after it make the adding and print out the answer, the user press a button and then continuing to input another number

Answer (score 4):

Just add an infinite loop inside your main function like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int SUM(int a){
int sum=0;
while(a>0){
    sum =sum+(a%10);

    a=a/10;

}

return sum;
}

int main(){
    int x;
    char quit = 'n';
    do{
        printf("Enter an integer = ");

        scanf("%d", &x);

        printf("Sum digit = %d", SUM(x));

        //exiting option 
        printf("Quit the program? [y/n]");
        scanf(" %c",&quit);
    }while(quit !='y' && quit != 'Y');   
}
```

also, the line that contain the SUM(x) function before the printf is redundant.

EDIT: I inserted an option to quit the inifinite loop at the end of each iteration - if you dont want that option, just change it to `while(1)` and delete both of the printing and scanf commands before the end.

Comment: At some time program needs to have gracious exiting, please handle that too.

Comment: That would be a great option to have

Comment: Made `scanf("%c",&quit);` -->`scanf(" %c",&quit);` in case `\n` is left out in stream.

Comment: @kiranBiradar is that working to clear the input buffer? I didnt know that option

Comment: It just clears the whitespace in the input buffer. Most format specifiers for `scanf` automatically filter any leading whitespace, but `%c` and `%[]` do not (so that the whitespace characters *can* be read if required to) but the added space instructs `scanf` to filter the whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to implement the infinite loop so that the sum value retains and another sum value can be added to it.
Hope this code Helps!!
Otherwise kindly improve your question

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int SUM(int a)
{
        int sum=0;
        while(a>0)
        {
                sum =sum+(a%10);
                a=a/10;
        }
        return sum;
}

int main()
{
        int x,choice,result=0;
        while(1)
        {
                printf("**MENU**\n");
                printf("1. Perform Sum\n");
                printf("2. Result\n");
                printf("3. Exit\n");
                printf("Choose:");
                scanf("%d",&choice);
                switch(choice)
                {
                case 1:
                        printf("Enter an integer = ");
                        scanf("%d", &x);
                        result+=SUM(x);
                        break;
                case 2:
                        printf("Sum digit = %d\n", result);
                        break;
                case 3:
                        printf("Final Result = %d\n",result);
                        exit(0);
                default:
                        printf("Try Again!\n");
                }

        }
        return(0);
}
```